# Add slug to user (RainLab) OctoberCms

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend, october-form-controller, october-partial

Is it possible to add a slug in the user table,
if it's possible, then how do?

I try to do it as usual, but it does not work with the table user

```
class User extends Model{
use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Sluggable;

protected $slugs = ['slug' => 'name'];

}
```

I add the slug field in the user table,
but it's still null

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

It will be little lengthy but No problem We will Solve it :)

> There are 2 ways of doing it.

1. Add direct field to `user` table and start using it and we are done.
2. Create other table `UserExtension` in database [ obvious with new plugin ] and add dynamic relation ship `oneToOne` to user table to this table and then save all new data to this table using relation.

> For now we should go for `1st` as seems you want only one `field` so

1. add actual field in to table [ database table ]
2. extend `backend forms` to show that field [saving data will work automatically]

> Create update script [ Class name => AddSlugToUserTable ] **file name** will be in snake case => `add_slug_to_user_table.php`. Add this file to your plugin's `updates` directory.

```
<?php namespace HardikSatasiya\Plugin\Updates;

use Schema;
use October\Rain\Database\Updates\Migration;

class AddSlugToUserTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function($table)
        {
            // make it nullable as we are adding it and existing records may not have any data for it so
            $table->string('slug')->nullable()->index();
        });

       // or even you can add converted data to slug field
       // from existing user name
    }

    public function down()
    {
        // don't want to mess with data so better be empty
    }
}
```

> Now add details about this file in `version.yaml` file. create this file if its not inside `updates` folder. [ **this file is very sensitive about spacing so use 2 space for tab and avoid extra spaces.** ]

```
1.0.1:
    - Initialize plugin.
1.0.2:
    - Adding Slug Field to User Table.
    - add_slug_to_user_table.php
```

> Next step will be adding Form Field to the `Backend Form` add this code to your `plugin.php => boot` method.

```
class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
    [...]

    public function boot()
    {
        // Extend all backend form usage
        \Event::listen('backend.form.extendFields', function($widget) {

            // Only for the User controller
            if (!$widget->getController() instanceof \RainLab\User\Controllers\Users) {
                return;
            }

            // Only for the User model
            if (!$widget->model instanceof \RainLab\User\Models\User) {
                return;
            }

            // Add an extra birthday field
            $widget->addFields([
                'slug' => [
                    'label'   => 'Slug',
                    'comment' => 'Add Slug To User',
                    'preset'    => [
                         'field' => 'name',
                         'type' => 'slug'
                     ]
                ]
            ]);

        });
    }
}
```

> Now `Logout` [ if you are already logged In ] from backend and `Login` again, to take effect all this stuff. Then Open `User From.`

[image]

You will see your shiny new `slug` field which can automatically filled from the `name` [ **you can change it from preset config** ]

if you get any problem or doubts please comment.